# How to align the xGrid lines with data points?

Tags: anychart

I have this chart: https://playground.anychart.com/5dBO9eg9/1

I would like the xGrid lines to start where the dates (2018-04-01, 2018-05-01, ...) are, so that they intersect the points on the chart.

Anybody has an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, you need to use a DateTime scale instead of an ordinal one. And then to set the ticks interval as one month to show all the dates. Please find the playground sample in the comment below.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the question, but breaks something else - I need the points to be uniformly spread, i.e. the distances between them to be the same (like with the ordinal scale), because I can have dates that are far apart. I tried setting the ticks manually https://playground.anychart.com/OJAtNTq0/3 , but that doesn't seem to be the way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible. You have dates on the xAxis, so the intervals between points are shown as they really are. Ordinal scale visualizes categories, that's why the distance is always equal.